# Upgrade old laptop with SSD and DDR3

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, memory, ssd, sata

I have this old laptop [HP Probook 450 G0](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03783671) - I want to buy a new SSD.

[This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp9LW.png) indicates that my laptop supports 1.5 and 3Gb/s speeds.

1. New SSD all go at 6 GB/s, does that work with my laptop? Or does the new SSD I buy have to be backwards compatible with my motherboard? (if they are not already?)
2. I checked that I run AHCI mode already so that is good, right?
3. As for the RAM, I have DDR3L 4GB at 1600MHz now, but it is hard to find this module. Would a 1866MHz module (2 x 8GB) also work with my laptop (max 16GB), provided it is backwards compatible with 1600MHz?

I'm trying to upgrade my laptop finally, but do not want to destroy it. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: https://www.crucial.com for the memory

Comment: This is a good set of questions, but the problem is that it's a set of questions. As it stands, this is likely to be closed for this reason. You should [edit] your question down to the most important one, and ask the others separately.

Answer (score 1):

You should be absolutely fine upgrading both the components that you mention.

- SATA is fully backwards compatible so you can use a 6Gb/s drive with no problems.
- AHCI is the correct mode to run in for SSDs.
- The RAM will run at a maximum of 1866MHz (out of the box) but will happily run at lower speeds such as 1600MHz if that is what your motherboard supports.